# Negative electric potential

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, conventions

I am studying about electric potential, and in particular electric potential around a point charge, by the formula we get that:

$$V_E=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Q}{r}$$

My question is: Can the potential be negative? i.e. if the point charge is of some negative charge, say $-P$ is it true that  $V_E=-\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{P}{r}$, or $V_E=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{|-P\ |}{r}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{P}{r}$.

Furthermore when dealing with two charges and the potential energy $U_E=qV$, is it $|q|$ or $q$ itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the potential and the potential energy ($U=qV$, not with a $|q|$) can be negative.

This actually is an essential feature, because if not, the potential near a positive charge would be same as the potential near a negative charge. This causes a lot of problems, for example, if this were true, positive charges would move **away** from negative ones!

In simple terms, our current framework that describes electromagnetism would make no sense if this were the case.

---

A handy thing to keep in mind is always the definition of electric potential, i.e. The work per unit of charge required to move a positive charge from a reference point to a specified point. (as an edit suggested)

Comment: "A handy thing to keep in mind is always the definition of electric potential, i.e. The work per unit of charge required to move a positive charge from a reference point to a specified point" Actually, infinity is the "specified point", isn't it?

Comment: It usually is convenient to assume so!